# clang-format: Why does disabling AlignAfterOpenBracket cause a line break?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have the following line

```
const float CELL_WORLD_WIDTH{SharedConfig::CELL_WIDTH * SharedConfig::TILE_WORLD_WIDTH};
```

With `AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align`, it gets formatted as such

```
const float CELL_WORLD_WIDTH{SharedConfig::CELL_WIDTH
                             * SharedConfig::TILE_WORLD_WIDTH};
```

With `AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign`, it gets formatted as such

```
const float CELL_WORLD_WIDTH{
    SharedConfig::CELL_WIDTH * SharedConfig::TILE_WORLD_WIDTH};
```

when I would expect it to be something more like

```
const float CELL_WORLD_WIDTH{SharedConfig::CELL_WIDTH * 
    SharedConfig::TILE_WORLD_WIDTH};
```

What's causing it to get that extra line break when set to `DontAlign`?

Full `.clang-format` file:

```
---
Language: Cpp
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveMacros: false
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands: true
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Inline
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  false
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum:       false
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  AfterStruct:     false
  AfterUnion:      false
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     false
  BeforeElse:      true
  IndentBraces:    false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeComma
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: true
ColumnLimit:     80
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 0
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DeriveLineEnding: false
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
    Priority:        2
    SortPriority:    0
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
    Priority:        3
    SortPriority:    0
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        1
    SortPriority:    0
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentGotoLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 2
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: false
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerAlignment: Left
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    false
SortUsingDeclarations: false
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Latest
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        4
UseCRLF:         false
UseTab:          Never
...
```